# Can we create a clickable python string that redirects users to a url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tkinter, href

I'm working on a tkinter project and I have used `tkinter.scrolledtext` to show the result of a searching operation, and what I want is a way to redirect each searching result in the scrolled text to a specified url.

my idea was to make the string in the scrolled text clickable and when I click, it will redirect me to the URL that I specify. Another solution is to add a button, but I have really searched about that but I didn't find a lot of documentation.

Any ideas, please!

Comment: Probably related, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436214/add-web-browser-window-to-tkinter-window

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `Listbox` instead of `ScrolledText`, below is an example:

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

def on_url_click(event):
    selected = event.widget.nearest(event.y) # find the index near the mouse click position
    url = event.widget.get(selected)
    webbrowser.open(url) # open the URL using default browser

root = Tk()

urllist = Listbox(root, width=80, height=20)
urllist.pack()
urllist.bind('<Button-1>', on_url_click)

# insert some URLs
for url in ('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.reddit.com', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'):
    urllist.insert(END, url)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: My problem is that the text in the listbox's items is too long and it should be written in two lines... and in listboxs I didn't find a way to write two lines in the same item, because `\n` is not working there!
any solution ?